# Фамилия Перлатов - от какого слова?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Если "Прелатов", то понятно, а в данном случае к какому слову отсылка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня только один вариант: от слова "перл", то есть, "жемчуг". Возможно, предки взяли эту фамилию сами, так сказать, для красоты, а может кто-то из предков занимался добычей жемчуга или его продажей.
Но это как вариант

Answer (score 3):

Вообще-то есть такое понятие как фонетическая инверсия, "Перлат" мог вырасти из "Прелата" в силу ослышки или сознательного искажения. Но мне в принципе не нравятся обе версии - что из "прелата", что из "перла". Во втором случае появление "латинского" суффикса просто необъяснимо, а "прелат" само по себе очень странно как основа для фамилии.

Так что ничего не остается, кроме как объяснять причудами предков. Взяли, например, да "перевели" на латинский фамилию "Жемчугов". Такие случаи известны...

Есть, правда, некий технический термин perlator - устройство для насыщения воды воздухом, но оно, кажется, происходит от некого искусственно образованного имени собственного. Для основы фамилии не годится.

Answer (score 2):

Могла занестись распространённая итальянская фамилия Perlato (как и имя; и сорт вина такой есть). Ещё распространена испанская фамилия Peralta и есть в испаноязычных странах более редкая фамилия Perlata. Во времена франкизма (когда у нас принимали испанских детей войны) фамилия могла попасть к нам. Возможно, что и через Peralta - видимо, перестановка букв с этой фамилией реально случалась.

Comment: Я думаю история фамилии потомков недавних эмигрантов должна быть хорошо известна носителям.

Comment:  Не факт, что про фамилию спрашивает носитель.

Answer (score 0):

Существуют **еврейские** фамилии на ПЕРЛ-: ПЕРЛИН, ПЕРЛИЧ, ПЕРЛОВ, ПЕРЛМАН, ПЕРЛОВИЧ, ПЕРЛОВСКИЙ, а также ПЕРЕЛЬМАН, ПЕРЕЛЬМУТЕР,  ПЕРЕЛЬРОЙЗЕН, ПЕРЕЛЬШТЕЙН. Можете увидеть эти фамилии подтверждённых евреев по интернет-ссылке "*Электронная книга памяти воинов-евреев, павших в боях с нацизмом (1941-1945)*", графа МЕМОРИАЛ, -  в нижней части страницы алфавитный указатель, - [link text](http://jmemory.org/). Фамилия ПЕРЛАТОВ, скорее всего, того же происхождения. Что она может означать на иврите или идише? - вероятно, от ей подобного имени; перевод мне неизвестен. Попробуйте поискать самостоятельно по ИРИС-словарю, -  [link text](http://www.slovar.co.il/translate.php), там есть поиск по транскрипции.

Comment: очень ненадежный источник.

Comment: "Перл" на иврите - то же, что и в русском - "жемчужина", но слово это заимствованное. В базовом языке есть "пнина". Все приведенные фамилии связаны именно с идишем - и опять "жемчужина". Так что версия со славянским окончанием -ов самая правдоподобная, кажется, у @behemothus'а. Любили наши предки красивость эдакую.